# DataTables with webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, datatables

I have some trouble using [DataTables](https://datatables.ne) with webpack... 
It is working fine when I compile in development mode but not in production mode...

*webpack.config.js :*

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

let config = {
  entry: {
    check_process_nomenclature: path.join(
      __dirname,
      'src',
      'js',
      'toto.js'
    ),
    user_login: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'js', 'tata.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'web', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'style')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /datatables\.net.*/, loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/i,
        exclude: [/(node_modules)/, /(ckfinder)/],
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|webp|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              publicPath: '/web/dist',
              name: '[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {}
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserJSPlugin({
        test: /\.js$/i,
        exclude: /\/node_modules/,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ]
  },
  stats: true,
  devtool: 'source-map'
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    config.mode = 'production';
    config.optimization.minimize = true;
  } else {
    config.mode = 'development';
    config.optimization.minimize = false;
  }

  return config;
};
```

*datatables.js :*

```js
import dt from 'datatables.net-bs';
import 'datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css';
import 'style/_datatables.css';
dt(window, $);
```

*toto.js :*

```js
import { productInformation, alertMsg, autoLogout } from './_common';
import './datatables';
import { modalOnHide } from './_modal_onhide';
import 'style/toto.css';

const $table= $('#table');
$table.DataTable({
  autoWidth: true,
  paging: true,
  lengthMenu: [
    [25, 50, 100, 250],
    [25, 50, 100, 250]
  ],
  ordering: true,
  info: true,
  stateSave: true,
});
```

*run :*
`webpack --mode=production`

*error :*
[image]
[image]

I have try to removed the `Terser` plugin and put all the `import` in the same js file without success.
If someone have any idea of how to solve this issue it would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found where was the error and has usual it was completely my fault... 
but difficult to find because somewhere unexpected (for me at least).

So in fact the "only" error which was causing this was because as I am learning webpack I read the [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) section of the manual and for some reason I copy and past a part of it in my package.json...

`"sideEffects": false`

Which was obviously a bad idea/error since everything is not in es6 in my modules (such as datatables but not only).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was putting this on top of the js-file where I do some datatable-extending:

```
import 'datatables.net';
import dt from 'datatables.net-bs';

dt(window, $);
```